# change regex to not include things inside [ and ]

Tags: php, regex

I have this auto linking regex code here:

```
// turn any url into url bbcode that doesn't have it already - so we can auto link urls- thanks stackoverflow

$URLRegex = '/(?:(?<!(\[\/url\]|\[\/url=))(\s|^))'; // No [url]-tag in front and is start of string, or has whitespace in front
$URLRegex.= '(';                                    // Start capturing URL
$URLRegex.= '(https?|ftps?|ircs?):\/\/';            // Protocol
$URLRegex.= '\S+';                                  // Any non-space character
$URLRegex.= ')';                                    // Stop capturing URL
$URLRegex.= '(?:(?<![.,;!?:\"\'()-])(\/|\s|\.?$))/i';      // Doesn't end with punctuation and is end of string, or has whitespace after

$body = preg_replace($URLRegex,"$2[url=$3]$3[/url]$5", $body);
```

The problem is if the url is inside quote tags and the end quote tag is right up against the link the end quote tag gets included in the link, which of course messes it all up!

How can I adjust that regex to not include anything inside [ and ] in the link?

Sample Input:

```
[quote=liamdawe] Have you had a look at [url=http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Serious_Sam_II#Linux_Installation]this howto[/url]? :)

http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Serious_Sam_II#Linux_Installation[/quote]
Testing
```

Correct Output would be:

```
<div class="quote"><strong>Quote from liamdawe</strong><br />  Have you had a look at <a href="http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Serious_Sam_II#Linux_Installation" target="_blank">this howto</a>? <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/smile.png" alt="" /><br />
<br />
<a href="http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Serious_Sam_II#Linux_Installation" target="_blank">http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Serious_Sam_II#Linux_Installation</a></div><br />
Testing
```

But the output I get is:

```
<div class="quote"><strong>Quote from liamdawe</strong><br />  Have you had a look at <a href="http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Serious_Sam_II#Linux_Installation" target="_blank">this howto</a>? <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/smile.png" alt="" /><br />
<br />
<a href="http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Serious_Sam_II#Linux_Installation </div>" target="_blank">http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Serious_Sam_II#Linux_Installation[/quote]</a><br />
Testing<br />
```

As you can see it has included the [/quote] tag within the link as it's not ignoring bbcode tags in the auto linker regex.

Here is the code that does that type of quote as well if needed:
    // Quoting an actual person, book or whatever
    $pattern = '/[quote\=(.+?)](.+?)[/quote]/is';

```
$replace = "<div class=\"quote\"><strong>Quote from $1</strong><br />$2</div>";

while(preg_match($pattern, $body))
{
    $body = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $body);
}
```

Comment: Show us code of before and after, please.

Comment: It's not relevant. This is all of the code that does the link.

Comment: Then it is not relevant to give you any help.

Comment: can u give a sample input, current output and desired output

Comment: Added samples, added quote code to show how its done too if needed.

Comment: Thanks, much more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY this

```
$URLRegex = '/(?:(?<!(\[\/url\]|\[\/url=))(\s|^))'; // No [url]-tag in front and is start of string, or has whitespace in front
$URLRegex.= '(';                                    // Start capturing URL
$URLRegex.= '(https?|ftps?|ircs?):\/\/';            // Protocol
$URLRegex.= '[\w\d\.\/#\_\-\?:=]+';                        // Any non-space character
$URLRegex.= ')';                                    // Stop capturing URL
$URLRegex.= '(?:(?<![.,;!?:\"\'()-])(\/|\[|\s|\.?$))/i';      // Doesn't end with punctuation and is end of string, or has whitespace after

$body = preg_replace($URLRegex,"$2[url=$3]$3[/url]$5", $body);
```